# Updating User field in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, spuserfield

I am harnessing batch update of SharePoint list in order to update my list items. I have a field of SPUser type named as 'UserName'.

If i try to update the value of that particular field using batch, am obtaining unexpected error.

I tried out both the username as well as the ID of the user. It was futile. How could I update a SPUser field in batch update? Any responses would be warmly welcomed

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the value to ID;#Username? ID is the SPUser.ID and Username is really just the display name or account name. Ex: 42;#Raghu.

Keep in mind, that a particular user's ID changes depending on what Site Collection you're working in (the same user in Site Collection A may have a different ID in Site Collection B).

You may have to use [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) to make sure the user exists on the web you are trying to update.

Comment: @above, yes you are right. I had to use the UserID instead of the Username. That worked like a charm :)

Answer (score -1):

To Set the user field value for particular item.

```
item["ItemOwner"] =web.EnsureUser("domain/administrator");
item.Update();
```